# Lenovo A916 cannot unlock bootloader

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bootloader-lock, lenovo

My PC OS is Gentoo Linux with Kernel version 4.4.21.
I'm followed these steps:

1. `adb reboot bootloader`
2. `fastboot oem unlock`

And after this, message pops up "... press Volume+ to continue, and Volume- to cancel", if i press "Volume+" button, nothing happens, and if i press "Volume-" button, operation cancels.

What i should do to fix it?

Or there are another way to unlock bootloader?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

1. `adb reboot bootloader`

Wait for your PC to install fastboot drivers for the device then

2. Check if device is detecting in fastboot mode

   `fastboot devices`
3. If device is detected use the following command to unlock bootloader:

   `fastboot oem unlock`

Follow the screen instructions and after unlocking reboot the device using the command:

`fastboot reboot`

Hope It will work for you.

**Note: Unlocking bootloader will erase entire data.**

Comment: Did you not see that he had already tried those? He just couldn't respond to the onscreen instructions.

Comment: @AndyYan Can't you see I suggested different commands. He was using adb oem unlock in fastboot which won't work. I have used fastboot command for oem unlock. Please read it carefully before replying.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he mistyped, since `adb` commands won't get response in fastboot, or else he wouldn't get the confirmation screen.